# How to make a Bootstrap dropdown with React

Tags: reactjs

I am a noobie at `React` and I am trying to make a `Bootstrap` dropdown.  The html that I am attaching to is here:

```js
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown">
</ul>
```

And here is what I want to put in my `render` method to insert inside of my html:

```js
render: function() {
  return (
      <li><a href="#books">Books</a></li>
      <li><a href="#podcasts">Podcasts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tech I Like</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#addBlog">Add a Blog</a></li>
    );
}
```

But of course I can only return one element.  What is the right way of doing this in `React`?  How could I add multiple `<li>`'s into a dropdown like this?  I tried wrapping the whole thing in a `<div>`, but that messes up my css.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[react bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) makes working with react & bootstrap a bit easier:

```
render: function(){
  return (
    <DropdownButton title="Dropdown">
      <MenuItem href="#books">Books</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem href="#podcasts">Podcasts</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem href="#">Tech I Like</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem href="#">About me</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem href="#addBlog">Add a Blog</MenuItem>
    </DropdownButton>
  );
}
```

This looks about the same, but has event-handlers & adds all the right classes. As @sophie-alpert said, though, `render` must return a single DOM parent element.

Comment: `react-bootstrap` wasn't around when I asked the question, but currently this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: When I use this, the dropdown isn't closing when I click an item in it.  I've seen the author of react bootstrap himself acknowledge that a lot of work needs to be done on the dropdowns.  So I think it's a bit too early for this to be the accepted answer

Comment: See this [issue](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/526) in react-bootstrap's github

Comment: Is there any documentation or examples of how to use the event handlers?   I can't even intuit what they are, let alone where/how to attach them...

Comment: Found it, right where it should be... https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#menu-items

Comment: Hi guys, does this component allows multiple level of navigation? or do you know one that do it?

Comment: As a related sidenote, [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/) is also very good.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately this is one situation where React's ability to return only a single node from `render` is annoying.  Your best bet is probably to return the `<ul>` itself from render:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <ul className="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#books">Books</a></li>
      <li><a href="#podcasts">Podcasts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tech I Like</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#addBlog">Add a Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
  );
}
```

then render that entire component into another container like a `<div>`. In a future version of React we're hoping to remove this restriction so that something like your original code will work.

Comment: should be `className="dropdown-menu"`.

Comment: Strange but when I add the classname `dropdown-menu` it fails to render the dropdown.  When I remove that classname it suddenly works but it moves the surrounding navbar (unwanted behavior)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) react component.It is very simple and easy to use.

```
var Select = require('react-select');

var options = [
{ value: 'one', label: 'One' },
{ value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
];

function logChange(val) {
console.log("Selected: " + val);
} 

<Select
  name="form-field-name"
  value="one"
  options={options}
  onChange={logChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to employ rebuilt dependencies like [react bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) to work with both react and bootstrap, **simply do the important js tricks which they do**. In your case, basically a `dropdown` click event toggles the popper wrapper with `.show` css class. So you can define an `onClick` method and toggle the class inside it. For example in the following code I get the *nextSibling* and then *toggle* the class name for it with `.show` and finally inner `div` will be shown:

```
<div className="dropdown">
    <a className="btn text-light" href="#" onClick={(e) => this.handleOption(e)}>open dropdown</a>
    <div className="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left dropdown-menu-arrow">
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">edit</a>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Note that this tricks help you in case of few bootstrap functionalities in your project***, otherwise employ rebuilt dependencies to have a clean and standard code.